# Objective Zip archives aren't opened by ArchiveUtility.app

Tags: ios, objective-c, zip, objectivezip

I'm using `ObjectiveZip` library (which is a wrapper for `MiniZip`) in my iOS app. My app sends .zip archives to server, where they are processed manually by moderator. Here's my code for creating an archive:

```
NSString * zipfile = [Result zipfilePathWithResult:self];
ZipFile * zf = [[ZipFile alloc] initWithFileName:zipfile mode:ZipFileModeCreate];
ZipWriteStream * zws = [zf writeFileInZipWithName:@"report.xml" compressionLevel:ZipCompressionLevelNone];
[zws writeData:[xml dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[zws finishedWriting];
for (NSString * name in mediaFiles)
{
    ZipWriteStream * zws = [zf writeFileInZipWithName:name compressionLevel:ZipCompressionLevelNone];
    [zws writeData:[files objectForKey:name]];
    [zws finishedWriting];
}
[zf close];
```

Unfortunately, these archives aren't correctly processed by default OS X ArchiveUtility: it always unarchives my files into zip.cpgz, regardless of the actual content of archive (usually it's a .xml file and a few .jpg files).

[image: unarchiving]

However, some other applications on OS X and also on Windows are able to open my archives correctly, so the archive isn't actually broken.

Is there a way to make ObjectiveZip work with ArchiveUtility? Or maybe you can suggest any other objective-c library for creating .zip files which can do it. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Edit zip.c changing the parameters passed into each calls to zipOpenNewFileInZip3_64.  The last parameter being passed into each method is a 1.  Change it to a 0 and it will work

Answer (score 0):

Changing the last parameter to zipOpenNewFileInZipX_64 function is one way to fix this but changing this parameter to 0 means setting zip64, i.e large file zipping capability, to false.

I was able to fix this by setting second parameter of **zip64local_putValue** call to **(uLong)20**(which is currently 45 in one case) inside the function **Write_LocalFileHeader** regardless of value of **zi->ci.zip64**.